# How do i run more than 1 Test Case in Python Webdriver. Only 1 of my test case class runs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In my automation page object model script I have created 2 TestCases so far with some test cases, methods.

class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

LoginPage has a test for testing a valid user login

AdministrationPage has 1 method so far add_Project (user can add a project after having logged in)

In the PyCharm editor I have AdministrationPage open.  I click the green run icon to run the test case.  I want to see if my method add_project works before i continue writing more methods.

When the test runs it runs the LoginPage Test Case and then it stops there.

How can i run the AdministrationPage Test Case?

Also If i wanted to run LoginPage Test Case first and then AdministrationPage to run when LoginPage has completed.  How can i do this?
Thanks!

My code is snippet for LoginPage and AdministraionPage is as follows:

LoginPage_TestCase.py

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from Pages import page
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element


class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")
        self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_login_valid_user(self):
        print "test_login_valid_user"
        login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        login_page.userLogin_valid()
        login_page.isAdministration_present()
        print login_page.isAdministration_present()
        assert login_page.isAdministration_present(), "Administration link not found"

    def test_login_invalid_user(self):
        print "test_login_invalid_user"
        #login_page = page.login(self.driver)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

AdministrationPage_TestCase.py

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from locators import locators
from locators import element
from Pages import page
from Pages.administrationPage import AdministrationPage
from Pages.page import LoginPage


class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")
        self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        print "I am here in setUp self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)"
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def add_Project(self):
        login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        login_page.userLogin_valid()
        administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration(self.driver)
        administration_page.AdministrationPage.add_project()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

AdministrationPage.py

```
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Locators.element import BasePageElement

class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class AdministrationPage(BasePage):

    # Add a project, enter project name & description, save
    def add_project(self):
        add_project_button = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.addButton_project)
        add_project_button.click()
        project_name_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.projectName_textfield)
        project_name_textfield.click()
        project_name_textfield.clear()
        project_name_textfield.sendkeys('LADEMO_IE_nn_')
        project_description_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.projectDescription_textfield)
        project_description_textfield.click()
        project_description_textfield.clear()
        project_name_textfield.sendkeys("LADEMO create a basic project test script - Selenium Webdriver/Python Automated test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your test methods should start with `test_`.

2) You should configure pycharm as:
[image]